# How to "guard against ever-changing result" in ExcelDna

Tags: excel-dna

I am implementing, and adapting, the sample code for array resizing found here: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/master/Distribution/Samples/ArrayResizer.dna

I have implemented one or two other sorts of functions (say `Resize(...)` and `NameRange(...)`, following a similar approach (use ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro() to perform some worksheet function)

The functions seem to work just fine when called separately. However, when nested (say `NameRange(Resize())`, Excel seems to go into an infinite re-calculation loop, particularly when there are other functions that reference the newly named range.

The code sample mentions including a guard against ever-changing results. Is this what's causing the re-calculations? What would/should such a guard look like?